# Why is this causing an error- Class within method Java

Tags: java, class, methods, static, binary

So I'm wondering why this is returning the error: "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method comparen(*args*) from the type Compn". I obviously cannot make the method comparen() static, so not sure what's wrong.

```
//8 bit comparison. bit 7 and bit 15 are highest.
public static boolean[] comparator(boolean bit0, boolean bit1, boolean bit2,
                boolean bit3, boolean bit4, boolean bit5,
                boolean bit6, boolean bit7,
                boolean bit8, boolean bit9, boolean bit10,
                boolean bit11, boolean bit12, boolean bit13,
                boolean bit14, boolean bit15) {

    boolean[] comparatorOUT = new boolean[3]; //0 == A>B, 1 == B>A, 2 == A==B
    boolean[][] currVal =  new boolean[16][3]; // [0] = highest bit.

    class Compn {
        boolean[] comparen(boolean curr1, boolean curr2, boolean curr3, boolean b1, boolean b2) {
            boolean[] storage = new boolean[3];
            storage[0] = curr3 && (((!xor(curr1, curr2) && b1) && !(!xor(curr1, curr2) && b2)) || curr1 && !curr2);
            storage[1] = curr3 && (((!xor(curr1, curr2) && b2) && !(!xor(curr1, curr2) && b1)) || !curr1 && curr2);
            storage[2] = curr3 && (!storage[0] && !storage[1]);
            return storage;
        }   
    }
    currVal[0] = Compn.comparen(false, false, true, bit7, bit15);
    currVal[1] = Compn.comparen(currVal[0][0], currVal[0][1], currVal[0][2], bit6, bit14);
    currVal[2] = Compn.comparen(currVal[1][0], currVal[1][1], currVal[1][2], bit5, bit13);
    currVal[3] = Compn.comparen(currVal[2][0], currVal[2][1], currVal[2][2], bit4, bit12);
    currVal[4] = Compn.comparen(currVal[3][0], currVal[3][1], currVal[3][2], bit3, bit11);
    currVal[5] = Compn.comparen(currVal[4][0], currVal[4][1], currVal[4][2], bit2, bit10);
    currVal[6] = Compn.comparen(currVal[5][0], currVal[5][1], currVal[5][2], bit1, bit9);
    currVal[7] = Compn.comparen(currVal[6][0], currVal[6][1], currVal[6][2], bit0, bit8);

    comparatorOUT[0] = currVal[0][0] || currVal[1][0] || currVal[2][0] || currVal[3][0] || currVal[4][0] || currVal[5][0] || currVal[6][0] || currVal[7][0];
    comparatorOUT[1] = currVal[0][1] || currVal[1][1] || currVal[2][1] || currVal[3][1] || currVal[4][1] || currVal[5][1] || currVal[6][1] || currVal[7][1];
    comparatorOUT[2] = !comparatorOUT[0] && !comparatorOUT[1];

    return comparatorOUT;
}
```

Comment: Why you cannot make `boolean[] compare` *static*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can call like this only when method is static.

```
Compn.comparen
```

you shold do it like this

```
Compn c = new Compn();
currVal[0] = c.comparen(false, false, true, bit7, bit15);
```

or change comparen to static.

and why don't you put Compn class outside the method?

Comment: I would prefer the method itself to be "self sufficient". I am attempting to design circuitry in Java where a method represents a subcircuit. Having #comparen defined within the subcircuit makes it much more reusable. Thanks though, that helped.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, you can't make `comparen`static within `Comp`. But this also means you can't call it like it was static.

From your example, it is not clear why you need the class `Compn` at all. You can make `comparen` a static sibling method of `comparator`.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared a *local class*, which is a type of an *inner class*, which cannot declare static members. Java has this restriction for a reason: there is actually no point in declaring your class at all.

Move the `comparen` method to be a *sibling* of your *comparator* method, and then make it `static`. It doesn't capture any local state so there was nothing forcing you to introduce the class in the first place.

If you want to encapsulate `comparen` together with `comparator`, then you need a separate class for *both of them*. That is the only way to satisfy your goals with Java's language features.

Comment: How do I create a "sibling" method? Bear in mind that I would like to have everything encapsulated within the comparator method.

Comment: Declared side-by-side with `comparator`, a sibling in the syntax tree. My answer already demonstrates that I bear in mind your wish, even though it is not stated in your question.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't really understand how you would do that. Could you post some example code?

Comment: What do you mean by "do that"? Put `comparen` side-by-side with `comparator`?

Comment: Yes... Do you mean make both of them static methods?

Comment: That's right---if a method *can* be static, then it *should* be static, for simplicity.

Comment: The whole point of this was so that one method was inside another. It may not seem like it, but for later use this is best for what I am doing.

Comment: Yes, I got your point (which you do not mention in the question) in the meantime. I still maintain that it is not the best for what you are doing and if you are after some way of grouping the two methods, then place them both in the same nested class.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the method `comparen` is an instance method of class `Compn`. You cannot call instance methods without creating an instance of that class.